# Is there any way to fetch all field name of collection in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

Is there any way by which we can fetch the field(Column name) of a collection in MongoDb. Like we have in mysql as follows:

```
SHOW columns FROM table_name
```

Or any way to check if a particular field exists in a collection.

Answer (score 2):

First question no, as each doc in a collection is independent; second question yes (using `$exists`):

```
# Get the count of docs that contain field 'fieldname'
db.coll.find({'fieldname': {'$exists': 1}}).count()
```

Comment: Short & simple answer. +1 for it...but still waiting to accept any answer. Thanks Johnny

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB every entry can contain a different number of fields, as well as different field names, too. That's why such a command is not there in the Mongo APIs: in MySQL you can do it because every row will have the same number of column and same column names. In MongoDB wou cannot make this assumption. What you can do is to check if a field is there in the retrieved document simply by:

```
if field_name in doc:
    # Do stuff.
```

where `field_name` is the "column" name you want to check existence and doc is the current `doc` pointed by the cursor. Remember that `doc` is a dict, so you can treat it as you would treat any other dict in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Since each document is separate from the other there is no easy way to do this, however, if you wish to understand what you have in your collection you can use Variety as described here:

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/21923016898/meet-variety-a-schema-analyzer-for-mongodb

It basically Map Reduces your collection to find out what fields you have in it.

As @JohnnyHK said, you can check the existance of a field by using `$exists`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/

Answer (score 1):

This is not best practices but in the shell you can type

Object.keys(db.posts.findOne())

Note: this doesnt show you the inner keys in the object, you can use map reduce to resolve this but if your object is simple this pretty much does the task.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when I was dealing with some third party heterogeneous data and I solved it using map reduce on the entire collection , here is the js code I used in case you can find it useful:

```
function MapKeys() {      
var tmp,tmpEmpty,ChildObjTp,ChildIsAr; 
var levelCurrent=0; 
var record=this;
function isArray(obj) {return typeof(obj)=='object'&&(obj instanceof Array);}  
//function emptyIf(obj){if (obj=='tojson')   {return  ' ';} else {return obj+' '}; }  //@note date fields return .tojson so strip it
function emptyIf(obj){if (typeof(this[obj])=='function')   {return  ' ';} else {return obj+' ';} }  //@note date fields return .tojson so strip it
//var toType = function(obj) {      // * http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/
//    return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase() 
//  }
function keysToArray(obj,propArr,levelMax, _level) {
    /** example: r1=keysToArray(doc,[null,[] ],2,0) 
        _level is used for recursion and should always called with 0
        if levelMax is negative returns maximum level
        levelMax=0 means top level only 2 up to 2nd depth level etc.
    */ 
        for (var key in obj) { 
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
                if (obj[key] instanceof Object && ! (obj[key]  instanceof Array))  
                    if (levelMax < 0 || _level+1  <= levelMax) { 
                        {propArr[1].push(keysToArray(obj[key],[key,[] ],levelMax,_level+1));}
                    }
                    else {}  //needed coz nested if ?  
                {propArr[1].push(key);} 
            }
        } 
        return  propArr;
    } 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function arrayToStr(lst,prevKey,delimiter, inclKeys,levelMax,_level,_levelMaxFound) {
    /** example: r2=arrayToStr(r1,'','|',true,2,0,0)
        _level and _levelMaxFound is used for recursion and should always called with value 0
        if levelMax is negative returns maximum level
        levelMax=0 means top level only 2 up to 2nd depth level etc.
    */ 
        var rt,i;
        _levelMaxFound=Math.max(_level,_levelMaxFound);
        if (prevKey !=='') {prevKey += '.';}
        var rtStr ='';  
        if (lst[0])     {prevKey += lst[0]+'.';} 
        if (inclKeys)   {rtStr += prevKey.slice(0,-1);} 
        for (var n in lst[1]) {
            i=lst[1][n];
            if (typeof(i)=='string') {
                rtStr += delimiter + prevKey + i;
            }
            else
            {
                if (levelMax < 0 || _level+1  <= levelMax) {
                    rt=arrayToStr(i,prevKey.slice(0,-1),delimiter, inclKeys,levelMax,_level+1,_levelMaxFound);
                    rtStr += delimiter + rt[0];
                    _levelMaxFound=Math.max(rt[1],_levelMaxFound);
                }
                else {} 
            }
        }
        if (rtStr[0] == delimiter) {rtStr=rtStr.slice(1);}  // Lstrip delimiters if any
        return [rtStr,_levelMaxFound]
    }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var keysV=keysToArray(this,[null,[] ] ,parms.levelMax, 0);   // we can't sort here coz array is nested
keysV = arrayToStr(keysV,'',' ', parms.inclHeaderKeys,-1,0,0); 
var MaxDepth=keysV[1];
keysV=keysV[0].split(' ');  // so we can sort 
keysV.sort();               // sort to make sure indentical records map to same id 
keysV=keysV.join(' ');
emit  ({type:'fieldsGrp',fields:keysV}, {cnt:1, percent:0.0,depth:MaxDepth,exampleIds:[this._id]});}

function ReduceKeys (key, values) { 
//var total = {cnt:0,percent:0.0,exampleIds:[]}  
var total = {cnt:0, percent:0.0,depth:values[0].depth,exampleIds:[]}
for(var i in values) {
    total.cnt += values[i].cnt; 
    if (total.exampleIds.length < parms.Reduce_ExamplesMax){ 
        total.exampleIds = values[i].exampleIds.concat(total.exampleIds);  
        }
    } 
return total;}
```